# Unable to access collection from custom model, returns null

Tags: module, custom

I have been trying to access 2 custom created tables which store additional values for a particular order, I am trying to implement a form that saves these details. I am trying to get the last id of the table and increment it by one.

/app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_LinkCustomTable>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_LinkCustomTable>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mycompany_linkcustomtable>
                <class>MyCompany_LinkCustomTable_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>linkcustomtable_resource</resourceModel>
            </mycompany_linkcustomtable>

            <!-- model vs db table relation -->
            <linkcustomtable_resource>
                <class>MyCompany_LinkCustomTable_Model_Resource</class>
                <!-- db table with name pax and trip details -->
                <entities>
                    <paxdetails>
                        <table>mycompany_pax_details</table>
                    </paxdetails>
                    <tripdetails>
                        <table>mycompany_trip_details</table>
                    </tripdetails>

                </entities>
            </linkcustomtable_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <linkcustomtable_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </linkcustomtable_write>
            <linkcustomtable_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </linkcustomtable_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Tripdetails.php 
(and app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Paxdetails.php is similar)

```
<?php
class MyCompany_LinkCustomTable_Model_Tripdetails extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {   
    $this->_init('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails');
    }
}
?>
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Tripdetails.php
(and app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Paxdetails.php is similar)

```
<?php
class MyCompany_LinkCustomTable_Model_Resource_Tripdetails extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails', 'trip_id');
    }
}
?>
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Tripdetails/Collection.php
(and app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Paxdetails/Collection.php is similar)

```
<?php
class MyCompany_LinkCustomTable_Model_Resource_Tripdetails_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails');
    }
}
?>
```

But when i call the getCollection method on

```
Mage::getModel('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails')
```

ie,

```
Mage::getModel('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails')->getCollection();  //->getLastItem()->getData('trip_id');
```

i get null value, tough there is a row in the mycompany_trip_details table.

I am sure that I am calling the right model because if I specify a different uri for getModel(), I get a error stating called getCollection() on boolean. I am not sure as to why I am unable get the collection from my custom tables. And if i uncomment the last part in the command

ie,

```
Mage::getModel('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails')->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getData('trip_id');
```

I get getLastItem() called on boolean (Mage::getModel('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails')->getCollection())

Comment: Have you used magerun to test the class alias? You can also do it from a shell script

Answer (score 2):

You have to fix your folder structure:

`app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Tripcollection`

and

`app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Paxcollection`

should be

`app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Tripdetails`

and

`app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Paxdetails`

according to name of your entities:

```
            <entities>
                <paxdetails>
                    <table>mycompany_pax_details</table>
                </paxdetails>
                <tripdetails>
                    <table>mycompany_trip_details</table>
                </tripdetails>

            </entities>
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo actually

"app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Tripcollection" was "app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Tripdetails "  and "app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Tripcollection" was "app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Tripdetails"   I have edited above accordingly.

Comment: so your collection should be in `Resource/Paxdetails/Collection.php`.

Comment: again, your collections should be in `app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Tripdetails/Collection.php ` and class `MyCompany_LinkCustomTable_Model_Resource_Tripdetails_Collection`, same for `Paxdetails`

Comment: I corrected the path and made it to app/code/local/MyCompany/LinkCustomTable/Model/Resource/Tripdetails/Collection and also changed the class but no use.

Comment: please fix your current post and show changes you've made, (including colleciton path and classnames) it is unclear right now what can be problem

Comment: also, fix your inits in your models from `$this->_init('linkcustomtable/tripdetails');` to `$this->_init('mycompany_linkcustomtable/tripdetails');`

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I have updated my question with appropriate changes in place.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working. Might be that was the cache, that was holding changes. Somebody please up vote this answer for me, Since I don't have enough reputation :(